# Is it possible to intercept directx 11 calls and convert them to directx 12?

Tags: directx-11

I read about directx 12's multiple gpu functionality. I was wondering if it was possible to capture directx11 calls and converting them to directx12, adding the multi gpu support.

This would enable directx11 games to also use the multi gpu support without developers rewriting the game.

My question is; is this do able, and fast enough so it makes sense to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, unfortunately.  Architecture between DX11 and DX12 is significantly different.  There is a great Microsoft presentation on youtube presenting the difference in API interfaces and functionality between the 2 including a discussion corresponding functionality between them.

DX11 takes alot of the overhead around boilerplate code away, in DX12, it removes this luxury but with the benefit that you have more granular control over your own drawing pipeline.